# How do I fix my SD card after it was split into multiple drives by Windows loT core?

Tags: sd-card

I installed Windows loT core onto my SD card and used it for my Raspberry Pi. Upon deleting the OS, I found that my SD card had been split into multiple drives. Is there a way to fix this? I can't add a screenshot as an unexpected error occurred.

[image]

Comment: Did you try to format the card?

Comment: Which one of the 4 drives?

Comment: You format the card itself as a whole, you don't choose a partition. Save your data first from all partitions.

Comment: I can't format it as a single drive. All of my computers see the SD card as seperate drives

Comment: @Ramhound Using the word _drive_ is justified IMO. Consider _drive letters_ - they are assigned to partitions (volumes), not disks.

Comment: @Ramhound Microsoft itself is [using the word _drive_ for partitions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t7qcX.png). We can either accept their terminology or argue that partitions aren't drives and add to the confusion. By the way, if we want to be pedantic, SSD disks aren't drives (no moving parts, nothing being driven). Drive is a fuzzy term and we have to deal with it.

Answer (score 13):

The *Disk Management* tool may not let you work on SD cards and flash disks with partition tables. `diskpart` will work, though.

1. Open the Start menu, type `diskpart` and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>. You may have to confirm UAC prompt.
2. Type `list disk` <kbd>Enter</kbd>. Take note of card's disk number.
3. `select disk X` <kbd>Enter</kbd> (`X` is disk number from previous command.
4. `clean` <kbd>Enter</kbd> - this will overwrite partition table with zeros - **all data will be lost**.
5. 'create partition primary' <kbd>Enter</kbd> - this will create a partition.
6. Now simply format the disk and it is ready to use.

Comment: Downvoter: I'll be happy to improve this answer, but I don't know what's wrong with it. Please don't downvote silently, always leave an explanatory comment or upvote existing one.

Answer (score 9):

Firstly, you need to run **diskmgmt.msc** - if you have Windows 10, just click start, then type "diskmgmt.msc", right click it, choose to start it as administrator. You should get something like on the screenshot below. Then you just right-click every volume on your sd card, and delete it. After you deleted them all, you can create one also by right clicking on empty/unassigned space on sd representation.

[image: Disk Management console]

Comment: nothing happens when I do this.

Comment: Me, neither - @gronostaj's solution worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

Diskpart and diskmgmt.msc did not work for me on my microSD after installing miner firmware and it was split into about 5 drives. I used Android (maybe an otg adapter if it's a flash drive or an app but I don't think it's necessary) to format it, it will say to repair the drive and then it worked perfectly, every time!

Answer (score 1):

Diskpart and diskmgmt.msc did not work for me on my microSD, and formatting it with Windows did not work, but formatting it with the SD Association Formatter worked:
https://www.sdcard.org/downloads/formatter/sd-memory-card-formatter-for-windows-download/

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Easy and fastest way. Put SD card into old camera
let the camera format the card. Put back into PC to use.

Comment: This worked fantastic.. in less than 5secs. No hassles.. nothing.. if you really want to wipe out everything this is the best way :)